# How to stop scrollIntoView at footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using scrollIntoView so when I select an option, the next option is unhidden, and it scrolls to that next option. But if a set of options doesn't have many choices it scrolls down enough that the footer takes up half the screen. So I want to scroll to the next set up options to the top of the screen(already working) but stop at the footer. scrollIntoView doesn't have any offset options in the docs.

`el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });`

Comment: ur already targetting `el`.  Why do u need offset ? u can use `scrollTo` with offset

Comment: Not necessarily an offset, I just don't want any of the footer to scroll into view.